# ngx-countdown Notify is not working in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

When 1 hour is remaining it sholud call notify For that I set 3600 second in notify.but it's not working

html file code:

```
<countdown #cd [config]="remainingduration" (event)="handleCountDown($event)"></countdown>
```

ts file code:

```
@ViewChild('cd', { static: false }) public countDownTime: CountdownComponent;


      timeCountdown(time){
            if (time > 3600) {
              this.remainingduration = { leftTime: time, format: 'HH:mm:ss', notify: [3600] };
              this.showHours =true
            }
      } 



 handleCountDown(event) {
        console.log(event)
    }
```

Comment: Did you start the countdown with `this.countdown.begin();` in your component? You also need to import it via @ViewChild at first

Comment: Yes I added via @Viewchaild but It should decrase time which I alredy give. "this.countdown.begin()" it's starting countdown from bigining I don't want it

Comment: When do you call your `timeCoutdown(time)` Function? In `ngOnInit()`? Do you define an initial default value for `this.remainingduration`?

Comment: Yes, I not assign default value. now assign default value and it's work

Comment: Glad it worked for you then ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example worked for me as you expect:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <countdown [config]="timerConfig" (event)="handleCountDown($event)"></countdown>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  timerConfig = { leftTime: 3610, notify: [3600] };
  
  handleCountDown(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

After 10 seconds the event of "**action: notify**" was fired

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CountdownComponent } from 'ngx-countdown';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <countdown #cd  [config]="{leftTime: timeData, notify: [ 3600]}" (event)="handleEvent($event)"></countdown>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('cd', { static: false }) private countdown: CountdownComponent;
  timeData = '3605';
  constructor() {}

  handleEvent(event) {
    console.log(event)
  }
}
```